# A recreational problem

Tags: number-theory

Let be $rad(n)$ the radical of a integer $n$. So for $n=2^2\cdot3^4\cdot7^{11}$, $rad(n)=2\cdot3\cdot7$, you take the prime factors without considering the exponents.

Now for $n=6$, you have $rad(6!+1)=7\cdot103$. If you concatenate base ten from the smallest to the greatest prime factor, you get $7||103$=$7103$, which is a prime.

Now consider $rad(n!+1)$, it must have at least two distinct prime factors. 
Are there other primes other than $7103$, which are the concatenation base ten of the prime factors (from the smallest to the greatest) of $rad(n!+1)$?

Other examples found with Pari: for $n=19$ and $n=23$.

If you consider $rad(n!-1)$ instead I did not yet found up to prime $67$ an $n$ which is prime and does the job!

The solutions for $rad(n!-1)$ so far found are for $n=15,21,22,25$ which are all semi-primes.

Comment: @Arthur can you find other examples?

Comment: I don't understand your claim, "it must have at least two distinct prime factors". Lots of numbers of the form $n!+1$ are prime: http://oeis.org/A002981

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Ethan MacBrough n!+1 must not be prime otherwise you cannot concatenate at least two elemets

Comment: $n=19$ gives the prime $711713311273363831$.

Comment: @Chrystomath yes

Comment: $n!+1$ has a few notable examples. $n!-1$ is a real devil.

Comment: @Peter@Chrystomath consider $rad(n!-1)$, a solution is for n=25 that gives prime $149907114776274341482621993$, which is the greater of a twin pair prime!

Comment: I have checked $n!-1$ all the way up to 78, with no luck (there is no prime n producing the requested result). I'm stuck at 79, seems that factorization of 79!-1 will take an eternity and a day.